# Записать в результрующий массив число и какое количество раз в исходном массиве это число встречается

Tags: c++, c

```
int const length = 20;
int arr1[length];
cout << "Исходный массив: \n";
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    arr1[i] = -20 + rand() % 41;
    cout << arr1[i] << " ";
}
cout << "\n\n";

int const arr3 = 40;
int flag = 0;
int arr_3[arr3];
cout << "Число и количество повторений: \n";
for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    arr_3[i] = arr1[i];
    for (size_t j = i+1; j < length; j++) {
        if (arr1[i] == arr1[j])
        {
            flag++;
        }
    }
    arr_3[i + 1] = flag;
    flag = 0;
}
for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++){
    cout << arr_3[i] << " ";
}
cout << "\n\n";
```

В целом вроде все правильно делаю, но выводится просто изначальный массив и все.

Comment: получается, что делаете правильно, а компилятор вас подводит?

Comment: Не тратьте время, ни своё ни моё, не можете помочь, не пишите. 
"Початиться" можно в другом месте.

Comment: Я просто удивлен,  что  вы определили   int const arr3 = 40; чтобы наверняка определить колчество вхождений этого числа, а в итоге вы его вообше игнорируете. И зачем нужен массив , чтобы написать всего одно число?...

Comment: В смысле одно число? Мне нужно каждый элемент массива записать во второй массив и следующим числом -  сколько раз оно встречается. Ровно в два раза больше массив.

Comment: Ну, если все числа, тогда для чего  arr3?

Comment: @k3rnelpan1c почему он должен быть в два раза больше? Например, в вашем массиве 20 раз будет записана цифра 3. В итоге результирущий массив, будет из 40 чисел?

Comment: Если смотреть только на ваш код, то arr_3 длины 40, а вы выводите только первые 20 элементов. Замените в последнем цикле I < length на I < arr3 и посмотрите, что будет выводиться. Это для начала.

Comment: @Sublihim в условии задания было указано сделать результирующий массив в два раза больше, вот я и сделал. Вобщем что дальше то? Как сделать, что бы работало правильно?

Comment: @АмирЗакиров Если изменить на arr3, то видно, что остальная часть массива заполнена мусором.

Comment: я бы посоветовал воспользоваться отладчиком. Код делает ровно то что написано. (Кстати 21 элемент не мусор).

Comment: Так никто и не подсказал, как сделать то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int const length = 20;
int arr1[length];
```

В новых версиях компиляторов это является ошибкой.  `length` должен быть константным выражением, а не константным обьектом, чтобы его значение было известно во время компиляции.

```
constexpr int length = 20;
int arr1[length];
cout << "Исходный массив: \n";
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    arr1[i] = -20 + rand() % 41;
    cout << arr1[i] << " ";
}
cout << "\n\n";
```

теперь вам нужен массив, в котором нужно записывать. Простейший вариант: проверяем сколько раз повторяется первое число в массиве, записывем результат.  Проверяем следующее и т. д., и можете сразу вывести на экран.

```
constexpr int sz = 2 * length;
int res[sz], count = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; ++i) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < length; ++j) {
        if (arr1[i] == arr1[j]) {
            ++count;
        }           
    }
    res[i] = arr1[i];
    res[i + 1] = count;
    count = 1;
    cout << res[i] << '\t' << res[i + 1] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Ну раз тег С++ то например так:

```
map<int,int> c;
std::for_each(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>(), [&c](int x){c[x]++;});
std::for_each(c.begin(),c.end(), [](auto &&r){cout << r.first<<"->"<<r.second<<endl;});
```

Comment: Дело в том, что я даже не понимаю, что здесь написано. Тег с++, просто для внимания. Как мне проще это решить?

Comment: @k3rnelpan1c вот пример запускаемый https://ideone.com/FDjqmA

Comment: но это мне ничего не дает.